# Let be $A_n$ the alternating group $n\geq 5$. How to prove that $\operatorname{Stab}_{A_n}(x) \cong A_{n-1}$, for all $x \in \{1, ..., n\}$?

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, simple-groups

MY ATTEMPT:

I have 3 properties in hand:

1. $H\trianglelefteq G \iff Hg=gH, \; \forall g \in G \iff gHg^{-1}=H, \; \forall
    g \in G$;
2. When $H=gHg^{-1}, \; \forall g \in G$ then we have $H\trianglelefteq G \iff G=N_{G}(H)$;
3. When we have an action over conjugative of a subgroup than $\operatorname{Stab}^{*}(H)=N_{G}(H)$

So my try is: By the properties above we have $H \trianglelefteq A_n \iff A_n=N_{A_n}(H)=\operatorname{Stab}_{A_n}(x)$.

So, How can I find that $\operatorname{Stab}_{A_n}(x) \cong A_{n-1}$? For me doesn't make sense.

$*$ Where Stab means stabilizer.

Comment: Prove the stabilizer of $n$ is $A_{n-1}$ directly. Then show that the stabilizer of $i$ is conjugate to the stabilizer of $n$.

Comment: By the way, “your try” cannot possibly be correct. What you wrote would yield, if the problem is correct, that $A_{n}\cong A_{n-1}$, and surely you see that cannot possibly be true. This has **nothing** to do with normal subgroups and normalizers.

Comment: Thanks for the hint and the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you involve normal subgroups and the sort. What I believe you wish to show is the following:
Consider the set $[n] = \{1, \ldots, n\}$ and the action of $A_n$ given on it by $\sigma\cdot x = \sigma(x)$.

Now, the stabiliser of an element $x\in [n]$ will be the set (subgroup) of all those $\sigma \in A_n$ such that $\sigma(x) = x$.
In other words, $\sigma$ restricted to $X = \{1, \ldots, n\}\setminus\{x\}$ is a bijection from $X$ onto itself.

Thus, the stabiliser is isomorphic to the symmetric group on $X$. (This is because composition of restrictions behaves well and thus, the group operation is respected.)

As $|X| = n-1$, the result follows.

Comment: How can I show that the stabilizer is ismorphic to the symmetric group on $X$?

Comment: Given $\sigma \in \text{Stab}_{A_n}(x)$, simply map it to $\sigma|_X \in S_X.$ This mapping is a bijection (quite straightforward). This is a homomorphism because of what I was writing in the brackets: the restriction of composition of bijections (that fix $x$) is the composition of the restrictions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.